# Reactjs GET METHOD fetching data from an api in a table

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks

this is what i have in the component file

```
<div>
      <Table striped>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#Number</th>
          <th>item</th>
          <th>description</th>
          <th>quantity</th>
          <th>price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {items && items.map(item => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{item.id}</th>
              <td>{item.items.map(item => <tr>{item.description}</tr>)}</td>
              <td>{item.items.map(item => <tr>{item.item}</tr>)}</td>
              <td>{item.items.map(item => <tr>{item.quantity}</tr>)}</td>
              <td>{item.items.map(item => <tr>{item.price}</tr>)}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
```

and this is my json from the api

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "invoiceno": "invoice1",
    "description": "invoice1",
    "taxrate": 10,
    "issuedate": "2021-07-14T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-07-15T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "invoice1",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 100,
    "total": 100,
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-26T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 14,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "createdBy": 25,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "item1",
            "item": 25,
            "quantity": 23,
            "price": 23,
            "idInvoice": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "item2",
            "item": 23,
            "quantity": 15,
            "price": 12,
            "idInvoice": 1
        }
    ]
}
 ]
```

i want to get the items only but when i put them in a table they keep showing in the same row like this picture i want them to be seperated what am i doing wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVSHA.png)

this is the GET METHOD function i m using so you can see it well

```
     const [items, setItems] = useState([])

     const getItems= () => {
     fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/invoice/${urlElements[4]}`, 
       {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-business-name' : 'billings',
    "Accept":"application/json"
  },

})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(items => setItems(items))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      getItems()
     }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't nest a `tr` directly inside a `td`, but still - it's doing what your code says. You have the first row printing the main object's id (#1) into that first `th`, and then you open a `td` and iterate each child `item` into a `tr` which, in your case, means each `td` has two entries (child item 1 and child item 2).

**Update** - your state `items` is an array and then you want the nested `items` in each one too. Here's an example based on the part of your code I can see and some stuff I had to make up because I can't see all of it.

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
  // Renaming so it's more clear and doesn't conflict with the
  // child `items`
  const [itemsFromApi, setItemsFromApi] = useState([])
  
  // Renaming
  const getItemsFromApi = () => {
  fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/invoice/${urlElements[4]}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-business-name' : 'billings',
    "Accept":"application/json"
  },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setItemsFromApi(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsFromApi()
  }, []);

// itemsFromApi is an array, so you either need to get
// itemsFromApi[0] for the first object in the array,
// or if you want to iterate all of the itemsFromApi, you'll
// need to handle that in a loop too.

// If you just want the first itemsFromApi object
  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#Number</th>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {itemsFromApi.length > 0 && itemsFromApi[0].items && itemsFromApi[0].items.map(item => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{item.id}</th>
                <td>{item.description}</td>
                <td>{item.item}</td>
                <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )

// Or if you want a full table for each of the itemsFromApi objects
  return (
    <div>
      {itemsFromApi.map((itemFromApi) => (
        <Table striped>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#Number</th>
              <th>item</th>
              <th>description</th>
              <th>quantity</th>
              <th>price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {itemFromApi.items && itemFromApi.items.map(item => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{item.id}</th>
                  <td>{item.description}</td>
                  <td>{item.item}</td>
                  <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                  <td>{item.price}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: i have a problem when i try your way of mapping  {items.items && items.items.map(item => { instead of the long version i m using it doesnt show anything in the table (i copied your same code ) i dnt know whats wrong

Comment: My bad. Try it now - I changed it to `item.items` and also renamed `item` to `rowItem` in the map function to avoid problems because you already have `item` defined.

Comment: but i have const [items, setItems] = useState([]) so it should be items.items but it still doesnt work like this the names are so similair they got me so mixed up

Comment: If that's what you have, and then your state `items` is an array of json objects, and inside each json object is an array of `items`, I need to see more of your code. Because the code I posted would work if you ran it for a single one of the `items` in your state, but your state is an array so we're missing a level of looping/iteration which I can't solve without more of your code for this component.

Comment: is my GET missing something

Comment: thank you it works now i appreciate your help so much